# Trying to combine+pivot(?) two tables in MySQL each with values not present in the other

Tags: mysql

I'm putting together a little company dashboard showing who's working on what projects, month to month.  I'm trying to combine two similar tables; one `Timesheets` and the other `Projected Hours`.

```
Timesheets
+---------+-------------+------------+-------+
| YearMo  | Employee ID | Project ID | Hours |
+---------+-------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-01 | Joe         | A          |    50 |
| 2018-01 | Joe         | B          |    50 |
| 2018-01 | Joe         | C          |    50 |
| 2018-01 | Mary        | A          |    50 |
| 2018-01 | Mary        | B          |    50 |
| 2018-01 | Mary        | C          |    50 |
| 2018-02 | Joe         | A          |    50 |
| 2018-02 | Joe         | C          |    50 |
| 2018-02 | Mary        | A          |    50 |
| 2018-02 | Mary        | B          |    50 |
| 2018-02 | Mary        | C          |    50 |
+---------+-------------+------------+-------+

Projected Hours
+---------+-------------+------------+-------+
| YearMo  | Employee ID | Project ID | Hours |
+---------+-------------+------------+-------+
| 2018-02 | Joe         | A          |    50 |
| 2018-02 | Mary        | A          |    50 |
| 2018-03 | Joe         | A          |    50 |
| 2018-03 | Joe         | D          |    50 |
| 2018-03 | Mary        | A          |    50 |
| 2018-03 | Mary        | E          |    50 |
| 2018-03 | Mary        | C          |    50 |
| 2018-04 | Joe         | A          |    50 |
| 2018-04 | Joe         | B          |    50 |
| 2018-04 | Joe         | E          |    50 |
| 2018-04 | Mary        | F          |    50 |
| 2018-04 | Mary        | C          |    50 |
| 2018-04 | Bob         | A          |   100 |
+---------+-------------+------------+-------+
```

Both `Timesheets` and `Projected` are summarized monthly and have unique combinations of (`YearMo`, `Employee ID`, and `Project ID`).  `Projected Hours` may have people working on different sets of projects from Timesheets, and there might be new employees that don't show up in `Timesheets` at all, but are projected to be working on things later (like "Bob").

I'd like to be able to join them and display the results like this: [Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfSYF.png) (Blue highlighting just meant to make it easier to look at)

Basically, for each Project, per month, I want to see the current hours worked in one column, as well as the projected hours 2 (or more) months out.  So, for all the rows where `yearMo=2018-01`, `Projected1` and `Projected 2` are `2018-02` and `2018-03`, but for the rows where `yearMo=2018-02`, `Projected1` and `Projected 2` are `2018-03` and `2018-04`.  I only want the `yearMo` column to include months from the `Timesheets` table, but I still need to include rows where an employee may not have logged timesheet hours on a project, but DO have hours projected in the coming months.

The code below is my partial solution which produces something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVBXy.png), but it only includes rows present in `Timesheets`, omitting any rows where `Actual Hours` is null.  I know the `LEFT JOIN` is omitting the additional rows I want.  I've played around with UNIONS, but I just haven't been able to get it.

```
SELECT a.yearMo
, a.`ID Number`
, a.`Project ID`
, MIN(a.Hours)
, MIN(CASE 
        WHEN b.yearMo = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(a.yearMo,'-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%Y-%m')
        THEN b.`Hours` 
        ELSE NULL 
    END
    ) AS `Projected1`
, MIN(CASE 
        WHEN b.yearMo = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(a.yearMo,'-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 2 MONTH),'%Y-%m')
    THEN b.`Hours` 
    ELSE NULL 
END
) AS `Projected2`
FROM `Summary_Timesheet` a
LEFT JOIN `PROJECTED` b
    ON b.yearMo BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(a.yearMo,'-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),'%Y-%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(a.yearMo,'-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 2 MONTH),'%Y-%m')
    AND a.`ID Number` = b.`ID Number`
    AND a.`Project ID` = b.`Project ID`
GROUP BY `ID Number`, `Project ID`, yearMonth
ORDER BY yearMo, `ID Number`, `Project ID`
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I was able to get a solution.  I don't know if it's the most efficient, but here's my solution for anyone interested: (I renamed some fields, but they should be pretty self evident.)  One thing I'm still nervous about is that I was using 2 months Projected for the example, but ultimately I want to show 6 months out.  Not entirely sure how 6 UNIONS are going to perform.

```
SELECT min(displayMo) as displayMonth
    , min(`ID Number`) as `Employee ID`
    , min(`Project ID`) as `Project ID`
    , MIN(CASE 
                WHEN displayMo = yearMonth
                THEN sumHours
                ELSE NULL 
            END
    ) AS `Timesheet Hours`
    , SUM(CASE 
                WHEN displayMo = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(yearMonth,'-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL -1 MONTH),'%Y-%m')
                THEN sumHours
                ELSE NULL 
            END
    ) AS `Projected Hours1` 
    , SUM(CASE 
                WHEN displayMo = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(yearMonth,'-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL -2 MONTH),'%Y-%m')
                THEN sumHours
                ELSE NULL 
            END
    ) AS `Projected Hours2`
FROM (
    SELECT a.yearMonth as displayMo, a.* 
    FROM Summary_Timesheet a
    UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(b.yearMonth,'-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL -1 MONTH),'%Y-%m') as displayMo, b.* 
    FROM PROJECTED b
    UNION
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(c.yearMonth,'-01'), '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL -2 MONTH),'%Y-%m') as displayMo, c.* 
    FROM PROJECTED c    
) merged
WHERE displayMo BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(ST.yearMonth) FROM Summary_Timesheet ST) 
                                AND 
                                (SELECT MAX(ST.yearMonth) FROM Summary_Timesheet ST)
GROUP BY `ID Number`, `Project ID`, displayMo
ORDER BY displayMo, `ID Number`, `Project ID`
```